# Can I configure tmux to show seconds of current time upon Prefix t?

Tags: configuration, tmux, time

On `Prefix t` (by default `Ctrl+b t`), tmux displays the time, and it looks something like this:

[image: Terminal showing 17:45 with large fonts and tmux bottom bar]

Is there any way to configure this, e.g. to show the seconds, too?

I tried setting `export LC_TIME="%H:%M:%S"`, but it didn't help. Everything I found was about tweaking the time and date format in the status bar.

Comment: Searching for "clock" in the [official manual](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1) does not indicate this is possible for now, so probably the answer is "no". As a workaround run `tty-clock -cs` in the pane.

Comment: If you would be happy with just minutes and seconds, you could edit a copy of the tmux binary and replace the string `%H:%M` with `%M:%S`. You need to keep the same number of characters.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at the source, the string that's used is hardcoded.

https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/608d113486835515e7a89b1511704440c68ae817/window-clock.c#L226

So it's just a "small matter of programming" to let this be configurable.